# How do I iterate through two data frames and perform a certain action when the values match?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames (df1,df2) and I want to iterate through both the data frames and match the key values in the two data frames. If matched I want to perform a specific action.

```
df1:
ID  Name   lat/long
1   xyz    (23,12)

df2:
ID   Store     lat/long
1    pharmacy  (23,13)
```

I want to iterate through the two df and find the distance between the two co ordinates where ID is the same.

Example
if df1['id'] == df2['ID']:
Find distance between two lat/lon

Comment: please provide more details, including an example input (as text) and the matching expected output

Comment: I have could you have a look

Comment: is ID a unique identifier for each row, or could the same ID value occur on multiple rows?

Comment: By ID I mean the store ID which is going to be the same in both data frames

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided a lot of information in the question, so this might be off.

Assumptions:

```
df1 =
   ID Name  lat/long
0   1    A  (23, 12)
1   2    B  (24, 12)
2   3    C  (25, 12)
3  10    D  (30, 12)

df2 = 
   ID Store  lat/long
0   1     a  (23, 13)
1   2     b  (24, 13)
2   3     c  (25, 13)
3  11     e  (30, 13)
```

And: the columns `lat/long` contain `tuples`. If not do `df1["lat/long"] = df1["lat/long"].map(eval)` and the same for `df2`.

Then this

```
from haversine import haversine

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how="inner")
df3["Distance"] = df3[["lat/long_x", "lat/long_y"]].apply(
    lambda row: haversine(*row),
    axis="columns"
)
df3 = df3.drop(columns=["lat/long_x", "lat/long_y"])
```

leads to

```
   ID Name Store    Distance
0   1    A     a  102.355413
1   2    B     b  101.581547
2   3    C     c  100.776739
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was looking for!